# Database Design/Performance – Location search based on city/town covered by company

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, location

** **PHP/MySQL used here** **

**Scenario:**

A delivery company has many depots/warehouse throughout the country, each depots covers only selected city/town.  When a user visit their site they can search for nearest/local depots.

**I looked into two options, each explained below:**

**Option One (Won’t work):**

I stored each depots with Latitude and Longitude and do a simple radius search, So when the user enters their city/town I used Google maps to Geocode and run a radius query to bring all depots that are  within 25 miles, this does work.

But it has a big drawback, some depots don’t cover selected town/city and radius search does not take this into account, resulting it will show depots/warehouse in the results even if they don't cover that area.

**Option Two:**

Store a list of town/city in one db table and depots in another table. Then have a relationship table, links depots to towns/city they cover. The users have to enter exact city (mySQL `LIKE` used here) name to return the results, this will search city table and then do a `LEFT JOIN` to depots table.

The drawback here is the relationship table will grow rapidly can have upto 5 million records, this might have performance issues at later stage.

**Database design for option two:**

Depot Table

```
-   ID
-   D_NAME
-   D_ADDRESS
-   D_POSTCODE
-   D_TEL
-   AND SO ON…
```

City table

```
-   ID
-   NAME
```

Relationship table

```
-   ID
-   CITY_ID
-   DEPOT_ID
```

**Questions:**

Are there any other options i can take?

Is Option two, the correct approach and is it OK in terms of performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the relationship table you are describing. As long as the city table has an composite index on the search term (city name, I assume) and the foreign key ID, that should work flawlessly.

You won't want to offer full wildcard search (`LIKE %ancouv%` to find Vancouver), but should limit searches to a prefix search (`LIKE vancou%`). Otherwise the index will not be helpful and the database server would have to do full table scans.

When testing, use the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` command to ensure your index is used. Also, you should always test with realistic amounts of test data. If you only have a small set of test data, the query optimizer might choose a different path than it would with the aforementioned millions of rows. For example, with a very small table, it might decide that doing a full scan instead of an index lookup might be a better approach, leading you to believe the index is never use.